# active/inactive check not working while login cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am having a user table with an active field datatype enum(1,0) for my cake php application

I want to dis allow the inactive users from logging into my application. For this i added this code in my Appcontroller.php

```
  public $components = array('Acl', 'Session',
      'Auth' => array('authorize' => array('Controller'),
          'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
          'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
          'Form' => array('userModel' => 'User'),
          'all' => array('scope' => array('User.active' => 1)))
  );
```

My user model is User

But this is allowing the in active users also to login to the application.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: dont use enum, use tinyint(1) with 0/1 as values only. don't forget to clear the cache after changing your db schema.

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: is there anything else i should do

Comment: Use `AuthComponent::ALL` instead of `'all'` as documented: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authorization-handlers - even though they should both work. Try to put your scope directly below the authenticate array otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check your array it is wrong assing

check below array and it will work for you

```
public $components = array(
'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array(
        'controller'    => 'users',
        'action'        => 'login'
    ),
    'authError' => 'Je hebt geen toegang tot dit gedeelte',
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
            'scope' => array('is_admin' => '1')
        ),

    )
),
'Session'
```

);

Comment: liyakat might be right, the array might close too early. hard to tell from the unformatted array.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've dealt with enums in CakePHP, their value is always a string. Therefore I think the problem you're encountering is that `1` is not equal to `'1'`.

For your active field, try using the `BOOLEAN` datatype which is a synonym of `TINYINT(1)`. You should then write in your `Auth` component configuration:

```
public $components = array('Acl', 'Session',
    'Auth' => array('authorize' => array('Controller'),
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    'Form' => array('userModel' => 'User'),
    'all' => array('scope' => array('User.active' => true)))
);
```

Semantically, I feel this makes more sense.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `all` with `AuthComponent::ALL`? ([Source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers))